# Есть ли возможность установить строковую переменную в Toolbar

Tags: android

Есть некий тулбар с каким-то title'ом

```
Toolbar toolbar = activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_app);
toolbar.setTitle(intResStr); // из ресурсов
```

Нужно добавить к этому title'у строку, которую я получаю из БД в текущей активити.

```
String nameString = dataModel.getName();
toolbar.setTitle(intResStr + nameString); // error
```

Понятно, что последняя строка не пройдет так как получает интовую и строковую переменную, но как реализовать подобное?
Спасибо!

Comment: обернуть инт в стринг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У метода         `toolbar.setTitle();` есть два параметра один на вход принимает `@StringRes` те строку ресурсов это int, а другой принимает на вход CharSequence, считайте это обычный String.

Для того чтобы орагнизовать второй способ для вас, нужно использовать вторую перегрузку метода, а строку вытащить из ресусов, выглядить будет примерно так:

```
toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.intResStr) + nameString);
```

...

```
<string name="intResStr">Что-то пишу</string>
```

Comment: Возможно, `context.getString(R.string.intResStr) + nameString`?

Comment: Да да, канеш getString, спасибо